# Eclipse IDE converts jar directly to executable jar. How to create jar file?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to create just a jar file from my eclipse project, however when I export it it automatically converts to executable jar file. I am unable to convert it to zip also. How do I fix this?

I go to my project->export->jar file->export java source file and resources. Upon exporting it has become a executable jar

Comment: Use _File > Export...: General > Archive File_ for that (assuming the JAR file should contain only the sources but not the compiled `.class` files).

Comment: @mariumali And what sould the JAR file contain? The sources?

Comment: @howlger yeah..

Comment: The first checkbox (_Export generated class files and resources_) is to include `.class` files. The third checkbox (_Export Java source file and resources_) is to include `.java` files. In your case, your JAR should at least contain the `.java` files. Is this not the case? Why do you say it is an _executable_ JAR?